# Overlaping faces

Tags: modeling

i have a problem with my mesh. It seems like the faces are overlaping with another faces. I try to clean the mesh but it doesnt help.

I dont know when it happends, i want to avoid make the retopoly again XD.

Any ideas?

thanks in advanced.[image]

I cleaned the mesh clicking in Mesh (edit mode) --> Clean up --> Merge by distance

I tried to clean the mesh

Comment: Could you edit the question with the edit link below it and add some info about specifically how you tried cleaning the mesh? What did you do to clean it?

Comment: you could try to remove doubles with alt M > Merge By Distance. You could also try to remove the inner faces with Select (bottom menu bar) > Select By Trait > Non Manifold, then X to delete faces

Comment: I will re check the mesh in home 'cause i opened the model in other pc and it seems it have not the problem of the overlaping faces. I will take your advices and will let you know the news. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, i figure it out whats happening. The option "In Front" in Viewport Display was checked. It seems that create the overlaping effect. Thanks for the Help!